# Rails redirect from old URL to a new one that using slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

i have this structure for my new urls:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def product_path(product)
    unless product.category.nil?
      cat = product.category
      if cat.ancestry_depth.eql?(2)
        product_long_path cat.root, cat.parent, cat, product
      else
        product_short_path cat.parent, cat, product
      end
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb file

```
 get "/(*root_id)_(*subcategory_id)_(*category_id)_(*id)" => "products#show", :as => :product_long
  get "/(*root_id)_(*category_id)_(*id)" => "products#show", :as => :product_short
```

and my show action

```
  def show
    @product = Product.find_by_slug params[:id]
    cat = @product.category

    raise NotFound unless cat.slug.eql?(params[:category_id]) and cat.root.slug.eql?(params[:root_id])
    raise NotFound if cat.ancestry_depth.eql?(2) and !cat.parent.slug.eql?(params[:subcategory_id])
  end
```

How can i build up a redirect for `"products/:id"`, i have products with 2 and 3 category depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm do it the most obvious way: 
ProductsController, show action

```
@product = Product.find_by_slug params[:id]
if @product.nil?
  @product = Product.find params[:id]
  redirect_to @product.redirect_string and return
end
```

in Product model

```
  def redirect_string
    if category.ancestry_depth.eql?(2)
      "/#{category.root.slug}_#{category.parent.slug}_#{category.slug}_#{slug}"
    else
      "/#{category.parent.slug}_#{category.slug}_#{slug}"
    end
  end
```

But im not sure that this is most elegant solution, so im open for another solutions.